# Geometric meaning of a specific form

Tags: differential-geometry

Take a $1-$form $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(xdy-ydx).$ Geometrically, what does it mean for $\alpha_L (= \alpha(L)?) = 0$ for any ray $L$ through the origin?
Is it: Any vector that starts at the origin has length zero? If we measure the length of the vector with $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates we have $x=r\cos \varphi$ and $y= r\sin \varphi$ and  $\alpha = \frac 12 r^2 d\varphi$. A curve $\gamma\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ thus satisfies $\alpha(\dot \gamma)=0$ if and only if $\varphi\circ\gamma$ is a constant function, which to say that the $\gamma$ must run along ray through the origin.

One can think of the rays through the origin as a foliation of $\mathbb R^2\backslash 0$ and $\alpha$ as co-normal to the foliaton (that is, it vanishes along the tangent spaces of the leaves). In two dimensions *any* $1$-form that is nowhere zero comes with such a foliation, in higher dimensions this type of question is addressed by the Frobenius theorem.

Comment: You lost me on foliation but I will check it out, thank you very much for the response!!